# conditions for asymptotic comparison to hold

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, asymptotics, stability, mathematical-biology

I have the following simple dynamical system:
\begin{align}
x_1' &= a - f(x_2)x_1\\
x_2' &= bx_1 - cx_2,
\end{align}
where all parameters and initial conditions are positive. $f(x_2)$ is a positive and increasing function with respect to $x_2$. Suppose I want to study the asymptotic behavior of this system and decide to do the following.

First, I note that the more $x_1$ I have, the higher the production rate for $x_2$ will be. Secondly, I note that the larger $x_2$, the higher $f(x_2)$ would be. Thus I choose to replace $f(x_2)$ by a function $g(x_1)$ such that:

1. $g(x_1) > 0$ and $\frac{dg}{x_1} > 0$.
2. $g(x_1)$ gives the same fixed points for $x_1$ (perhaps through something like a quasi-steady-state-approximation for $x_2$).

Together, I obtain:
\begin{equation}
x_1' = a - g(x_1)x_1.
\end{equation}

Due to the construction, the asymptotic behavior of $x_1$ in this equation should be the same as that of $x_1$ in the original equation. I tried this out with $f$ and $g$ being simple hill equation and it works.

This is just a toy example. **My question is**: for higher dimension and more complicated functional responses, if I only care about asymptotic behavior, when can something similar be carried out? I would appreciate any references on this topic.

Comment: I'm just curious: have you proved anything rigorously even for this simple 2D system and if so, how? I completely agree that it is the simplest case to consider before trying to attack the general problem but can you really do it in full generality?

Comment: @fedja I only proved in the case $f$ and $g$ take the form of hill equation (unique steady state). The method that I used is Bendixon-Dulac criterion. And the approximation for $x_2$ is $x_2 \approx b/c x_1$. You are right about the problem with the generality, which is what I am asking in this post? I am curious if there is existing work on this topic.

Comment: @fedja Yes, for the system as given by the OP the global asymptotic stability of a unique equilibrium in the non-negative orthant can be rigorously proved, see [my comment on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207619/conditions-for-asymptotic-comparison-to-hold#comment6601218_3207619).